# Rcpp set the RNG state to a former state

Tags: r, rcpp

My question is a follow-up of http://rcpp-devel.r-forge.r-project.narkive.com/qJMEsvOK/setting-the-r-random-seed-from-rcpp.

I want to be able to set the RNG state to a former state from within C++.
For example, I would like the following code to produce a matrix where each column contains the same realizations of Gamma random variables.

```
cppFunction('NumericMatrix rgamma_reset_seed(int n, double shape, double rate){
            RNGScope rngscope;
            Environment g = Environment::global_env();
            Environment::Binding RandomSeed = g[".Random.seed"];
            IntegerVector someVariable = RandomSeed;
            NumericMatrix results(n, 2);
            results(_,0) = rgamma(n, shape, 1/rate);
            RandomSeed = someVariable;
            results(_,1) = rgamma(n, shape, 1/rate);
            return results;  
}')
m <- rgamma_reset_seed(1000, 1.2, 0.8)
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plot(m[,1])
plot(m[,2])
```

But it does not seem to work. In R, I can achieve the result by lines such as

```
.Random.seed <- x # reset the state to x
x <- .Random.seed # store the current state
```

Am I missing something obvious? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This may not work (easily) -- there is some language in Writing R Extension which states that you cannot set the seed from the C level API.

Now, you could cheat:

1. Init RNG from R
2. Do some work, make sure this is wrapped by `RNGScope` as our code does anyway.
3. Now cheat and use `Rcpp::Function()` to invoke `set.seed()`.
4. Consider whether to go back to step 2 or to finish.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that I want to do that repeatedly from within Rcpp code, so I wouldn't know which value to use in the `set.seed` call without "reading it" somehow from `.Random.seed`. It seems it'd be easier to code my algorithm in R with seldom calls to Rcpp functions, so that I could copy and restore the `.Random.seed` variable from within R. Am I correct?

Comment: I really don't know.  Maybe you want to consider using a different RNG engine?  Lots of trade-offs here.